# python - the string behind forward slash can't be find by re module

Tags: python

It seems a very simple problem, but this has taken me a few hours:

```
mystr='link/123'
pattern = re.compile(r'123')
print(pattern.match(mystr))
```

And result is `None`.
As I known, '/' is just a ordinary char, and I have no idea why `re` does not work?

Comment: Hint: Replace `pattern.match` with `pattern.search`.

Comment: `match` matches the start of the string. Did you want `search`?

Comment: its simple string why regex you can split the string by '/'

Comment: @heemayl and @tdelaney Thank you so much! I just learned the usage of `re.match` from a personal tutorial and didn't notice that at all. , and previously it happen to work for me. ah, it's a stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` will only match at the beginning of the string.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match

Use `search` instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search

Comment: Thank you so much! I just learned the usage of `re.match` from a personal tutorial and didn't notice that at all. , and previously it happen to work for me. It's a stupid question

Comment: That's OK mate. If the answer solves the problem you can accept it as the correct answer. @timchen